# Out of memory exception when adding data to the database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 27000 images that are stored in a folder and which need to be added to the database using EntityFramework. I have a code

```
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(file);

                var imgRes = ResizeImage(img, ImageSettings.Width, ImageSettings.Height);

                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                img.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

                var label = Directory.GetParent(file).Name;
                var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

                memoryStream.Close();

                db.Add(new ImageData { Image = bytes, Label = label });

                img.Dispose();
                memoryStream.Dispose();
                imgRes.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

it only works when there are less than 10,000 images otherwise I get Out of memory exception.
how can i upload my 27000 images to the database.

Comment: You appear to be properly disposing everything that needs disposing. Have you tried profiling tools to see where your memory goes? I would suspect `ResizeImage()` to use a `Graphics` object that doesn't get disposed or something like that.

Comment: There are no entities in that code so using an ORM is *definitely* wrong. The very fact you create the context *inside* the loop means you already got into trouble with using a single context. If you want to import data in bulk use SqlBulkCopy or any similar feature offered by your database provider.

Comment: Other problems that will definitely result in OOMs - `img` is never disposed. `MemoryStream`, which is just a wrapper over a buffer, has no initial capacity. That will result in *multiple* reallocations of the internal buffer until the memory is so fragmented there's no way to allocate a new buffer, resulting in ... an OOM

Comment: @CodeCaster the graphics object, like the imageattribute, also calls the dispose method and the memory of the process throughout the work 50mb

Comment: @fdgfggf allocating a byte[] buffer byte by byte results in `log2(50M)` reallocations. That's a lot of garbage. If you know how big the images are, pass that to the `MemoryStream` constructor. Better yet, create a big-enough buffer outside the loop and pass it to MemoryStream's constructor inside the loop, thus reusing the same buffer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code doesn't deal with entities or objects, so using an ORM doesn't help at all. This doesn't cause the OOM though, it only makes the code a *lot* slower.

The real problem is that `MemoryStream` is actually a wrapper around a buffer. Once the buffer is full, a new one is reallocated with double the size, the original data are copied over and the old buffer deleted. Growing a 50MB byte buffer this way results in a *lot* of reallocations, log2(50M). This fragments the free memory to the point the runtime can no longer allocate a large enough contiguous buffer. This results in OOMs with `List<T>` objects too, not just MemoryStreams.

The quick fix would be to pass the expected size as the stream's capacity through the [MemoryStream(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_MemoryStream__ctor_System_Int32_) constructor. This cuts down on reallocations *and* saves a lot of CPU cycles. The number doesn't have to be exact, just large enough to avoid too much garbage :

```
using(Image img = Image.FromFile(file))
using(var imgRes = ResizeImage(img, ImageSettings.Width, ImageSettings.Height))
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(10_000_000))
{
    img.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    var label = Directory.GetParent(file).Name;
    var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    db.Add(new ImageData { Image = bytes, Label = label });
}
```

There's no need to close `MemoryStream`, it's just a wrapper over an array. That still allocates a big buffer for each file though.

If we know the maximum file size, we can allocate a *single* buffer and reuse it in all iterations. In this case the size matters - it's no longer possible to resize the buffer :

```
var buffer=new byte[100_000_000];
using(Image img = Image.FromFile(file))
using(var imgRes = ResizeImage(img, ImageSettings.Width, ImageSettings.Height))
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    img.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    var label = Directory.GetParent(file).Name;
    var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    db.Add(new ImageData { Image = bytes, Label = label });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid creating `ApplicationContext` in `foreach` loop:

```
using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
{
    foreach(var file in files)
    {        
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using(Image img = Image.FromFile(file))
        using(var imgRes = ResizeImage(img, ImageSettings.Width, ImageSettings.Height))
        {
            var imgRes = ResizeImage(img, ImageSettings.Width, ImageSettings.Height);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            var label = Directory.GetParent(file).Name;
            var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            db.Add(new ImageData { Image = bytes, Label = label }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `BulkInsert` method in EF or EF Core. Bulk imports work through SqlBulkCopy. There *are* extensions that use `SqlBulkCopy` internally, but this will make things worse in this case. The DbContext will cache all ImageData objects until `BulkInsert` is called, causing the OOM that much faster.

Comment: Should you not improve the code a bit while you at it, and use the `using` clause for `MemoryStream`, `img` and `imgRes` as well? If not. Please explain.

Comment: OOMs are typically caused when reallocations result in such memory fragmentation that allocating a new contiguous buffer is impossible. In this case, adding 50MB of data to the MemoryStream byte by byte will cause a *lot* of reallocations

Comment: @StepUp  yes, I got this problem again

Comment: That's because the problem is caused by the MemoryStream, not the context. Using a single context will only make things crash faster

Comment: @Jaques yeah, I've improved code. Thanks for the comment. :)